# Transition from NM-B to THHN/THWN-2 for an attached garage subpanel

Tags: garage, subpanel, transition

This question is similar to others, however similar questions suggested are over 5 years old.  The work has not yet begun, but here is what I am thinking.  I am running a 50A 240V circuit from my main panel to a subpanel in my attached garage, for a new garage heater.  I do understand that I really don't need a subpanel for a single dedicated circuit, but I want to be able to shut down power to the heater at point-of-use.  The garage floor level is below the level of the first-floor floor joists.  From the main panel in the basement, I am running 6/2 NM-B by drilling through each first floor joist.  The run is less than 25 feet.  The last joist I drill through let's me go straight into the garage at the shared wall.  I plan to surface mount the subpanel in the garage on the wall that separates the garage from the house, approximately 5 feet up from the garage floor.  Once I am on the garage side, I plan to run the wires in an appropriate sized conduit.  My question is, do I need to put in an additional junction box on the last joist in the basement to simply change over from NM-B to THHN/THWN-2, so that I am running the THHN/THWN-2 in conduit instead of NM-B when I get into the garage, or can I run the NM-B all the way from the main panel to the garage subpanel (with or without conduit)?  I am totally open to other solutions or ideas.

Comment: Is the garage/house separation a frame wall, or...?

Comment: You can also run 6-6-6-6  or 2-2-2-4 SER cable. Which is 50A and 90A wire respectively, and about 1/3 the price of #6NM copper. There is nothing wrong with aluminum wire at these large sizes.  Since you're going to a garage, bring extra amps for EV charging; not for you, for home buyers. It really helps resale value.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Frame wall

Answer (score 3):

With an attached garage you can use NMB all the way to the panel. You need a 4 wire feed and the neutral must be isolated from ground. No additional ground rods are required since the garage is attached.

Comment: The wire in the garage, if run on the outside of the wall (exposed to potential damage), must be run in conduit to protect it from damage. NM-B can be run through conduit, it's just more difficult to pull. Run oversized conduit to ease the pull - one 5' section of conduit, even if huge, won't be all that expensive.

Comment: @FreeMan - Can I run NM-B in conduit from the subpanel to the heater?  The heater will be hardwired.  I thought NM-B shouldn't be run in conduit, or can it be in this situation?  It will be 15-20 feet from subpanel to heater.

Comment: @user149104 I'm sure Ed will confirm, but there's nothing at all wrong with, nor code that prevents, running NM-B in conduit so long as you don't exceed conduit fill limits. Cable requires _larger_ conduit than the 3 individual wires inside it would, and pulling cable through conduit is more difficult, so it's usually _recommended_ not to. However, for your short, 5', straight run, it shouldn't be too difficult. Whether you _choose_ to pull it to the heater is entirely up to you - if you've already got suitably sized _wire_, that would make the pull easier and require smaller conduit.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nm in conduit the conduit has to be appropriately sized and you have to be careful pulling NMB in conduit because cutting / scraping the sheath can fail an inspection. The sheath must be intact, can not be removed to pull into the conduit as the individual wires are not labeled. But a straight run is not hard. Inside the building envelop can’t go outside with NMB even in conduit for most locations.

Comment: @ freeman, @EdBeal - I've been thinking about this, and kind of still have my original question.  So I have conduit on the garage side of the shared wall to protect the cable.  On the house side there isn't any conduit.  So how do I go from my 2-2-2-4 (or NM-B) cable that isn't in conduit to a point where it IS in conduit?  What goes on the end of the conduit at the start point?  Is there a junction box on the end on the house side, or do I simply have an open end/stub of conduit that goes through the last floor joist and the cable is just fed into it?

Comment: Conduit requires a bushing on the open end to protect the insulation.